# question about limits of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the function $f_n:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  (n-1)x &\text{if $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$}
  \\\frac{n-1}{n} + (x - \frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{n-1}) &\text{if $\frac{1}{n} < x \le 1$}
\end{cases}$

For every $x\in[0,1]$, I am supposed to find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. So my thinking was to observe the limit of the two cases.

**Case 1:** Let $x\in[0, \frac{1}{n}]$. Then, I have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)= \infty$

**Case 2:** Let $x \in (\frac{1}{n}, 1]$. Then, I have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)= 1$ since $f_n(x)$ simplifies to $\frac{n-2+x}{n-1}$ in this case.

I was just wondering if this is correct?

Comment: When you write $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ you really fix $x$ first and then let $n \to +\infty$. So what does it mean for $x$ to be in $[0,1/n]$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: oh, so if $x \in [0, 1/n] $ as $n \to \infty$, then $x = 0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   But consider also what happens to the size of the support's pieces as $n\to\infty$.    In particular, what happens to $x\in\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}[0;1/n]$.